# Can not delete FK/ Constraint (index)

Tags: mysql

I have a table (see below) in which I added a compound foreig key to another table. I can not add rows to this table because the foreign key fails, even if the parent key has a record with the compound index values... So the table currently is empty.

The foreign key is realy not needed and the system would suffice with one Fk to the other table ID, so I tryed to my best to delete the foreign key to no avail, always getting the infamus 150 err.

Tried to stop foregn key check and then to delete the index, columns, bur could not delete either

This is may table...

```
CREATE TABLE `Servicios` (
 `Servicio_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `SolSer_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ConsecutivoServicio` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `ServicioAnt_ID` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `FechaAsignada` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha Asignada para el servicio',
 `HoraAsignada` time NOT NULL COMMENT 'Hora Asignada para hacer el servicio',
 `FechaServicio` date default NULL,
 `HoraServicio` time default NULL,
 `Tecnico_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Eq_ID` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `ObjetoReporte_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `TipoFalla_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `EnergiaRegulada` enum('Si','No') collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 `EstadoAlLlegar` varchar(500) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
 `DiagnosticoFalla` varchar(500) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
 `SolProp` varchar(500) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
 `Observaciones` varchar(500) collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
 `ResultadoServ_ID` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `RetiroEquipo` enum('No','Si') collate utf8_spanish_ci default NULL,
 `EstatusServ_ID` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `RecibeServicioInt` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `PuestoRecibeInt` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 `FechaRecibe` date default NULL,
 `HoraRecibe` time default NULL,
 `EstatusSolServ_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Empresa_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Empleado_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Servicio_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `FK_Servicios_SolServicio2` (`SolSer_ID`,`Empresa_ID`),
 KEY `Tecnicos` (`Tecnico_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_ResultadosServicio` (`ResultadoServ_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_EstatusSolServicios` (`EstatusSolServ_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_Servicios` (`ServicioAnt_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_EstatusServicio` (`EstatusServ_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_TiposFalla` (`TipoFalla_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_ObjetoReporte` (`ObjetoReporte_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_Equipos` (`Eq_ID`),
 KEY `FK_Servicios_Empleados` (`Empleado_ID`),
 KEY `Empresa_ID` (`Empresa_ID`),
 **CONSTRAINT `FK_Servicios_SolServicio` FOREIGN KEY (`SolSer_ID`, `Empresa_ID`) REFERENCES `solservicio` (`SolSer_ID`, `Empresa_ID`),**
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_37` FOREIGN KEY (`SolSer_ID`) REFERENCES `SolServicio` (`SolSer_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_38` FOREIGN KEY (`Tecnico_ID`) REFERENCES `Empleados` (`Empleado_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_39` FOREIGN KEY (`ObjetoReporte_ID`) REFERENCES `ObjetoReporte` (`ObjetoReporteID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_40` FOREIGN KEY (`TipoFalla_ID`) REFERENCES `TiposFalla` (`TipoFalla_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_41` FOREIGN KEY (`ResultadoServ_ID`) REFERENCES `ResultadosServicio` (`ResServ_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_42` FOREIGN KEY (`EstatusServ_ID`) REFERENCES `EstatusServicio` (`EstatusServ_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_43` FOREIGN KEY (`EstatusSolServ_ID`) REFERENCES `EstatusSolServicios` (`EstatusSolServ_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `Servicios_ibfk_44` FOREIGN KEY (`Empresa_ID`) REFERENCES `Empresas` (`Empresa_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

The offending constraint in bold. I tried

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

ALTER TABLE `Servicios` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_Servicios_SolServicio2`;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `Servicios` DROP INDEX `FK_Servicios_SolServicio2`;
```

But keep getting:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './segucom_SS8/#sql-2ca6_af6829' to './segucom_SS8/Servicios' (errno: 150)
```

Funny thing is the create table refers to this constraint as `FK_Servicios_SolServicio` and not as: `FK_Servicios_SolServicio2` (missing 2 at the end)

Here is the other table

CREATE TABLE `SolServicio` (
 `SolSer_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `Empresa_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `FechaSolicitud` datetime NOT NULL,
 `HoraSolicitud` time NOT NULL,
 `Solicito` varchar(20) collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 `SolVia_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `DescripcionFalla` varchar(264) collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 `Empleado_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `TipoServ_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `EstatusSolServ_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ServicioInicial` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`SolSer_ID`,`Empresa_ID`),
 KEY `IX_SolServicio2` (`Empleado_ID`),
 KEY `IX_SolServicio3` (`Empresa_ID`),
 KEY `FK_SolServicio_TiposServicio` (`TipoServ_ID`),
 KEY `FK_SolServicio_EstatusSolServicios` (`EstatusSolServ_ID`),
 KEY `FK_SolServicio_SolicitudVia` (`SolVia_ID`),
 KEY `FK_SolServicio_Empleados` (`Empleado_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `SolServicio_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Empresa_ID`) REFERENCES `Empresas` (`Empresa_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `SolServicio_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SolVia_ID`) REFERENCES `SolicitudVia` (`SolVia_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `SolServicio_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Empleado_ID`) REFERENCES `Empleados` (`Empleado_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `SolServicio_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`TipoServ_ID`) REFERENCES `TiposServicio` (`TipoServ_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `SolServicio_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`EstatusSolServ_ID`) REFERENCES `EstatusSolServicios` (`EstatusSolServ_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci

Comment: Yes, I am editing my question adding the other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, to me it looks like a typo: you have a Unique Key with the name of the foreign key you try to remove (`FK_Servicios_SolServicio2`). And you have a foreign key with the name `FK_Servicios_SolServicio` that you marked with ** in your script. Obviously you cannot remove a unique key with `DROP FOREIGN KEY`. I would suggest to try again with

```
ALTER TABLE `Servicios` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_Servicios_SolServicio`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry didn't read you already tried this

Try

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE `Servicios` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_Servicios_SolServicio2`;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: @Digital Precision I am modifying, not deleting constraints, the other table has a constraint on the other part of the compound index, so in the end I am not missing the "compound index" requirement,  I did not notice when I made the compund index.. tks anyway